# Update redux state when filter changes or new entitiy is created using NGRX

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, angular9

I am creating an app with Angular 9 and [NGRX](https://ngrx.io) where I have a post class:

```js
    class Post { 
      id: number; 
      title: string; 
      category: string;
     }
```

`ParentComponent` displays page 1 of posts and its child, `ChildComponent` displays Page 1 of posts with `category=book`.

At any moment, the page or category might change or a new post might be created ...

The database is large so I cannot load all posts into the Angular app.

I have a `PostService` with the method GetByQuery:

```js
    class PostService {
      GetByQuery(category: string, page: number) : Observable<Post[]> {
        // implementation 
      }
    }
```

How to update the state if the `page` or `category` changes or if a new `post` created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, provided information isn't enough because it doesn't show which actions and reducers you have.

Usually for such things when we need to do something extra than a reduce an action people use `effects` with them you can listen to the changes of `page`, `category` or new `post` and cause another actions, like `reload` data for example.

Here you can find all info: https://ngrx.io/guide/effects

An example (it's old one with decorators, currently createEffect function should be used).

```js
@Injectable()
export class ActivationAdminEffects {
    /**
     * Sending activation by admin request and processing its result.
     */
    @Effect()
    public readonly activate$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ActivationAdminActions.Activate), // <- waiting this action

        // doing side things we need
        mergeMap((action: ActivationAdminActionsActivate) =>
            this.http.post(this.urlActivationAdmin, action.data).pipe(
                mergeMap(() => {

                    // dispatching a new action once we are done.
                    return of(new ActivationAdminActionsActivateSuccess());
                }),
                catchError(
                    (error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<Action> => {
                        if (error.status === 404) {

                            // an expected error and dispatch of related action
                            return of(new ActivationAdminActionsActivateFailure());
                        }
                        return throwError(error);
                    },
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

    protected readonly urlActivationAdmin: string = `${environment.urlApi}user/activation-admin`;

    constructor(protected readonly actions$: Actions, protected readonly http: HttpClient) {}
}
```